# Working on a project at the same time on separate computers

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I'm building an app with android studio with another developer. Is there any way in which I can make it so that both my partner and I can work on the project at the same time on different computers (both Windows computers)? I know there is a similar question, but I am looking for a more detailed explanation on how to do it.

Comment: You can use a versioning system, like git. Free hosters are e.g. GitHub or gitlab.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: Use `Version Control` preferably `git`.

This will help both of you to develop Apps without any problems of copying & pasting and manually making changes in all files one-by-one.

Note: Want to use `git` but do not want to open source your code (since `Github` allows creating private repository but with some `Payment`), then use `Bitbucket`, you can create `private repositories` for FREE!

EDIT: Github now provides unlimited private repositories.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at git. I will help you and your partner to work on the same project on a different computer (Windows, Mac, Linux...).

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, you should use a version control system like `git` for this. This will give you the following features (among others):

- The ability to share code between people
- Essentially keeps a backup of your code on an external server
- Keeps a history of revisions to files (so you can "back out" changes if you need) as well as differences between your local file and the version on the server
- Allows you to merge changes between you and people working with you

How you do this will depend on which version control system you use, but some version control providers will allow you to also set up what's known as "Continuous Integration" - basically, if you or your partner check code in, it'll immediately start a build. If this is available to you, I *strongly* recommend using it. The advantage of that is that it'll give you quick feedback if you did something that'll prevent it from building for the other person (e.g. if you forgot to check in a file or something). This'll prevent a lot of frustration and wasted time. (This happens a lot more often than you'd think; you don't want the other person to have to spend half an hour trying to get the app to build again when they download your code only to find out that you forgot to check in a file).

I also *strongly* recommend integrating your stuff with each other as often as possible as well as practicing regular "re-baselines" (i.e. downloading each others' stuff and merging it with what you have locally). The longer you wait to integrate your stuff with each other the more complicated it'll become, and waiting too long *greatly* increases the risk of introducing bugs when merging or forcing unnecessary rework.